# Simple `yield` in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, this

I'm reading [this article](https://blog.embermap.com/good-ember-developer-bad-ember-developer-7f9d52c6a0b5) about lessons a developer has learned over the years of working with Ember.js

There's one point here that I'm curious about:

> Don’t `{{yield this}}`. Think carefully about how to yield as little as possible.

---

I understand technically what he's saying, but what's the reasoning behind it? Is there a performance problem with being able to access the whole `this`?

Comment: It's not a technical concern, it's about readable code.

Comment: @Lux to add to that, @qarthandso -- you don't know what is in `this`. if you want to yield a bunch of things, it's recommended to yield a hash, because you can explicitly see what will be yielded

Comment: Makes sense, thank you